# Master ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Recently i am started working on ASP.NET MVC ( along with Linq to SQL).I am finding it difficult and confusing ( concepts like repository , controller , view are confusing me.).
Can someone please tell me how to move or rather  how can i master MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I watched all the tutorials at http://www.asp.net/mvc (don't miss out on Scott Hanselman's "show"!), I used the book "Professional ASP.NET MVC 2". I worked through most of the text cover to cover and learned heaps along the way. The book is very well structured and provides new material in small enough increments. It was easy to follow and good to read.

The source code for all of it is available on the internet. The system is even live, see http://www.nerddinner.com.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you follow [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman/) tutorial.  Also, there are plenty of other tutorials and information on the [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site.

Also, download the NerdDinner or Music Store examples from the MVC site. You can look through the code, step through the code and get a general feel of how it works.

Try doing some test projects too - it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Read books, read blogs, read msdn, practice. Only way to learn is by trying.

Answer (score 0):

You could read my [blog post](http://alexandermp.com/post/2010/06/30/MVC-Model-View-Controller-description.aspx) to help get you started with the main concepts, then switch to books about ASP.NET MVC. I learned from Apress "Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework", but there are many more on this topic from Wrox, available on Amazon, eBay, bestbargainbook, etc.

Also, check out NerdDinner. It's an OpenSource project, with a tutorial in it, meant to help beginners get started.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the mentioned Nerddinner and music store examples I found this one also to be very interesting: [Tailspin travel](http://tailspintravel.codeplex.com/). I used it as base for one of my presentations about MVC2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

get a Tekpub.com subscription, and check out the series on ASP.NET MVC. it's brilliant! :)